# How do I send an event with gtk#

Tags: c#, gtk#

The title really says it all.

I have a few custom widgets that I want to respond to without doing too many ugly hacks -- that is, I would like to treat them in the same manner as I would treat, say, a button, and respond to any events from outside the widget itself.

To be a bit more specific, one of the widgets contains a list of buttons; when one of them is clicked, I need to modify data outside the widget depending on which button was clicked. I could give the widget an object (string in this case) to modify but I would rather avoid that and instead just do it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to add the right members to your widget;

```
[Glib.Signal("Activated")]
public event EventHandler Activated;
```

will add an eventhandler that you may invoke when your widget becomes ``activated'' (whatever that means). Simply add an `EventHandler` to the `Activated` member and you can treat your custom widget like a regular GTK# widget.

Answer (score 2):

Do not know if some examples with `Gtk#` which is a Graphical User Interface Toolkit for `mono` and `.Net`. That binds the gtk+ toolkit and assorted GNOME libraries would be useful for you.

You can learn several examples [from git](https://github.com/mono/gtk-sharp/tree/master/sample/GtkDemo). Take a look at this example that treats a button.

```
/* Drawing Area
 *
 * GtkDrawingArea is a blank area where you can draw custom displays
 * of various kinds.
 *
 * This demo has two drawing areas. The checkerboard area shows
 * how you can just draw something; all you have to do is write
 * a signal handler for the Drawn event, as shown here.
 *
 * The "scribble" area is a bit more advanced, and shows how to handle
 * events such as button presses and mouse motion. Click the mouse
 * and drag in the scribble area to draw squiggles. Resize the window
 * to clear the area.
 */

using System;
using Gtk;
using Gdk;

namespace GtkDemo
{
    [Demo ("Drawing Area", "DemoDrawingArea.cs")]
    public class DemoDrawingArea : Gtk.Window
    {
        private Cairo.Surface surface = null;

        public DemoDrawingArea () : base ("Drawing Area")
        {
            BorderWidth = 8;

            VBox vbox = new VBox (false, 8);
            vbox.BorderWidth = 8;
            Add (vbox);

            // Create the checkerboard area
            Label label = new Label ("<u>Checkerboard pattern</u>");
            label.UseMarkup = true;
            vbox.PackStart (label, false, false, 0);

            Frame frame = new Frame ();
            frame.ShadowType = ShadowType.In;
            vbox.PackStart (frame, true, true, 0);

            DrawingArea da = new DrawingArea ();
            // set a minimum size
            da.SetSizeRequest (100,100);
            frame.Add (da);
            da.Drawn += new DrawnHandler (CheckerboardDrawn);

            // Create the scribble area
            label = new Label ("<u>Scribble area</u>");
            label.UseMarkup = true;
            vbox.PackStart (label, false, false, 0);

            frame = new Frame ();
            frame.ShadowType = ShadowType.In;
            vbox.PackStart (frame, true, true, 0);

            da = new DrawingArea ();
            // set a minimum size
            da.SetSizeRequest (100, 100);
            frame.Add (da);

            // Signals used to handle backing pixmap
            da.Drawn += new DrawnHandler (ScribbleDrawn);
            da.ConfigureEvent += new ConfigureEventHandler (ScribbleConfigure);

            // Event signals
            da.MotionNotifyEvent += new MotionNotifyEventHandler (ScribbleMotionNotify);
            da.ButtonPressEvent += new ButtonPressEventHandler (ScribbleButtonPress);


            // Ask to receive events the drawing area doesn't normally
            // subscribe to
            da.Events |= EventMask.LeaveNotifyMask | EventMask.ButtonPressMask |
                EventMask.PointerMotionMask | EventMask.PointerMotionHintMask;

            ShowAll ();
        }

        protected override bool OnDeleteEvent (Gdk.Event evt)
        {
            Destroy ();
            return true;
        }

        private void CheckerboardDrawn (object o, DrawnArgs args)
        {
            const int CheckSize = 10;
            const int Spacing = 2;

            Widget widget = o as Widget;
            Cairo.Context cr = args.Cr;

            int i, j, xcount, ycount;

            // At the start of a draw handler, a clip region has been set on
            // the Cairo context, and the contents have been cleared to the
            // widget's background color.

            Rectangle alloc = widget.Allocation;
            // Start redrawing the Checkerboard
            xcount = 0;
            i = Spacing;
            while (i < alloc.Width) {
                j = Spacing;
                ycount = xcount % 2; // start with even/odd depending on row
                while (j < alloc.Height) {
                    if (ycount % 2 != 0)
                        cr.SetSourceRGB (0.45777, 0, 0.45777);
                    else
                        cr.SetSourceRGB (1, 1, 1);
                    // If we're outside the clip, this will do nothing.
                    cr.Rectangle (i, j, CheckSize, CheckSize);
                    cr.Fill ();

                    j += CheckSize + Spacing;
                    ++ycount;
                }
                i += CheckSize + Spacing;
                ++xcount;
            }

            // return true because we've handled this event, so no
            // further processing is required.
            args.RetVal = true;
        }

        private void ScribbleDrawn (object o, DrawnArgs args)
        {
            Cairo.Context cr = args.Cr;

            cr.SetSourceSurface (surface, 0, 0);
            cr.Paint ();
        }

        // Create a new surface of the appropriate size to store our scribbles
        private void ScribbleConfigure (object o, ConfigureEventArgs args)
        {
            Widget widget = o as Widget;

            if (surface != null)
                surface.Dispose ();

            var allocation = widget.Allocation;

            surface = widget.Window.CreateSimilarSurface (Cairo.Content.Color, allocation.Width, allocation.Height);
            var cr = new Cairo.Context (surface);

            cr.SetSourceRGB (1, 1, 1);
            cr.Paint ();
            ((IDisposable)cr).Dispose ();

            // We've handled the configure event, no need for further processing.
            args.RetVal = true;
        }

        private void ScribbleMotionNotify (object o, MotionNotifyEventArgs args)
        {

            // paranoia check, in case we haven't gotten a configure event
            if (surface == null)
                return;

            // This call is very important; it requests the next motion event.
            // If you don't call Window.GetPointer() you'll only get a single
            // motion event. The reason is that we specified PointerMotionHintMask
            // in widget.Events. If we hadn't specified that, we could just use
            // args.Event.X, args.Event.Y as the pointer location. But we'd also
            // get deluged in events. By requesting the next event as we handle
            // the current one, we avoid getting a huge number of events faster
            // than we can cope.

            int x, y;
            ModifierType state;
            args.Event.Window.GetPointer (out x, out y, out state);

            if ((state & ModifierType.Button1Mask) != 0)
                DrawBrush (o as Widget, x, y);

            // We've handled it, stop processing
            args.RetVal = true;
        }

        // Draw a rectangle on the screen
        private void DrawBrush (Widget widget, double x, double y)
        {
            var update_rect = new Gdk.Rectangle ((int)x - 3, (int)y - 3, 6, 6);
            var cr = new Cairo.Context (surface);

            Gdk.CairoHelper.Rectangle (cr, update_rect);
            cr.Fill ();

            ((IDisposable)cr).Dispose ();

            widget.Window.InvalidateRect (update_rect, false);
        }

        private void ScribbleButtonPress (object o, ButtonPressEventArgs args)
        {
            // paranoia check, in case we haven't gotten a configure event
            if (surface == null)
                return;

            EventButton ev = args.Event;
            if (ev.Button == 1)
                DrawBrush (o as Widget, ev.X, ev.Y);

            // We've handled the event, stop processing
            args.RetVal = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't look like it's what I need; as far as I can tell, it creates a custom widget from scratch without using any GTK widgets as a base -- I have a widget which is a combination of several widgets; I want to respond to one of those custom widgets being manipulated. I'll have a look at the git stuff though.